# Unicode Decode Error when trying to read data from a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, encoding

I am very new to python scripting but I have a very simple task that I would like to perform, but I seem to be stuck at it. All I am trying to accomplish is to read data from a .txt file and parse it.

**Steps I have taken**

1. I have downloaded the pdf file from my schools website, it contains a list of courses http://info.sjsu.edu/cgi-bin/pdfserv?ftok=soc-fall-courses
2. I converted the pdf file to a .txt file simply by saving it as a .txt file
3. Googled the error to find out that it is some sort of encoding issue
4. Used the terminal command file -I [filename] and returned the result `sjsuclassdata.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit`
5. Used the many methods online to try and convert the file to a UTF-8 encoding but to no avail

**Error Message that I got**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edward/MyPythonScripts/sjsuClassExtractor.py", line 25, in <module>
    regexMatches = lectureRegex.findall(file.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

So as you can see, I am really lost as to what Im supposed to do from here, I have verified that everything works if I read a different file that contains similar data.

Comment: "I converted the pdf file to a .txt file simply by saving it as a .txt file" Have you tried reading this file with a text editor? Because this is not how you convert a pdf into a text file.

Comment: @Rightleg You can open a PDF file in Acrobat Reader and "Save as" a .txt file. It will generate a proper (although not UTF-8 encoded) text file. Note how OP says "save as" and not "rename".

Comment: @Selcuk Oh my bad, I understood it as "save from the net as .txt". You know, if I said that, it's because I've seen a lot of people thinking renaming was tantamount to converting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the original text file is ANSI encoded (default with Acrobat Reader's 'Save As Text' option), this command will convert it to `utf-8`:

```
iconv -f "iso-8859-1" -t "utf-8" sjsuclassdata.txt -o sjsuclassdata-utf8.txt
```

Comment: Hi thanks, when I run the above in terminal it seems to do something for a quick second and then returns `iconv: -o: No such file or directory
iconv: sjsuclassdata-utf8.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @EdwardLim It looks like your platform's iconv doesn't have the `-o` argument. In this case, you can use `iconv -f "iso-8859-1" -t "utf-8" sjsuclassdata.txt > sjsuclassdata-utf8.txt`